# Automatically restart Tomcat on system reboots

Tags: boot, web-server, services

Trying to configure Tomcat for automatically start after boot or reboot my rpi, I follow these steps:

- The script /etc/init.d/tomcat8 rights:

  ```
  sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tomcat8 
  ls -la /etc/init.d/tomcat8 
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 665 Feb 14 21:23 /etc/init.d/tomcat8
  ```
- At the beginning of this file I have this line for debugging:

  ```
  echo "`/bin/date` $1" >> /var/tmp/tomcat8
  ```
- I can run tomcat manually and get the logs successfully in /var/tmp/tomcat8.

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat8 start
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo service tomcat8 start
  ```
- I create these symbolic links:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat8 /etc/rc1.d/K20tomcat8
  sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat8 /etc/rc0.d/K20tomcat8
  sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat8 /etc/rc6.d/K20tomcat8
  sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat8 /etc/rc3.d/S80tomcat8
  sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat8 /etc/rc4.d/S80tomcat8
  sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat8 /etc/rc5.d/S80tomcat8
  ```
- check the startup services:

  ```
  $ chkconfig -list tomcat8
  tomcat8  0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
  ```

Then I reboot the rpi. But tomcat doesn't run automatically and I am not getting any log in /var/tmp/tomcat.

Any hint?

Comment: what is the output of dmesg? what if anything appears in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: In "cat /var/log/syslog" nothing related with tomcat and with "dmesg" no error/warning.

Comment: Well, in answer to your first question, -rwxr-xr-x is 755. Are you saying you did a 755 and ended up with -rw-rw-r-x?

Comment: @DavidNedrow My first question was very ridiculous. I misundertood the size of the file (655). I thought it was the numeric form of the type access (-rwxr-xr-x), which obviously is 755. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should use `update-rc.d` to make/manage your soft links as I suspect they are missing rights.

Note that init scrips are normaly run with sh and no enviroment, use `printenv` to compare if you have issues after fixing the links.

```
/bin/echo "$(/bin/date) $1" >> /var/tmp/tomcat8
```

Answer (score 1):

I came accross the same problem you have. But I learned that raspbian has a default run level of 2, so all you require is

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat8 /etc/rc2.d/S80tomcat8
```

for your script to run at startup.

Comment: it's better to use `sudo update-rc.d tomcat8 defaults`, which will setup the proper start and stop symlinks.

Comment: I'd agree, but that had no effect for me. Though I have no clue why. They only way i could get the script to run on startup is by the above command.

Comment: you might need header info in your init script: https://gist.github.com/rca/c312ffd1a13fcf70338e